# setUserProperty() sometimes is not updating. React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

`setUserProperty()` sometimes is not updating. I have the following code:

```
async componentDidMount(){

    // Set screen event name.
    this.props.screenProps.firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen('Grocery Screen.'); // <-- This is updated correctly all the times

    // Log out that the menu wasn't opened to Firebase
    if(!this.categoryMenuWasOpened){
      await this.props.screenProps.firebase.analytics().setUserProperty('Category_Menu_Opened', 'No'); // This is **never** updated correctly
      console.log('Updated category menu "No".');
    }

    // Log out that the search bar isn't being used to Firebase
    if(!this.searchBarUsed){
      await this.props.screenProps.firebase.analytics().setUserProperty('Search_Bar_Used', 'No'); // <-- This is sometimes updated correctly
      console.log('Updated Search Bar "No".'); 
    }
  }
```

Why does this work sometimes? Am I calling in an inappropriate way the functions?

Comment: have you try to using await too in set screen event name ?

Comment: have you checked the logic of your conditions? The setCurrentScreen doesn't have any condition so it is updated correctly, so maybe this.categoryMenuWasOpened is always true and this.searchBarUsed is sometimes false?

Comment: Yes, searchBarUsed and categoryMenuWasOpened always are false.